# What is the optimal cell size for UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

iPhones come in different screen sizes and when UITableView cells appear on the screen they can be separated with a thin line. The cell line separator does not always align with the UITabBar. Certain cell sizes will align perfectly and some will not.

The UIStatusBar has a fixed point size and the UITabBar has as fixed point size
and the iPhone screen point sizes vary predictably.

**Does this mean one can have optimal cell sizes that align perfectly for all(some/most) devices?** And how do I solve my "Gap" problem if possible.

**Example:**

Screen Sizes:

- iPhone  6,  6s,  7 = 667 points
- iPhone 6+, 6s+, 7+ = 736 points

Components:

- Status Bar Size: 20 points : normal, 40 points with incoming call etc.
- Navigation Bar: 44 points
- Tab Bar: 49 points

UITableView Sizes:

- 667 - 20 - 44 - 49 = 554
- 736 - 20 - 44 - 49 = 623

Lets say you have a design with a cell size of 154,00.

For the iPhone 6s+: 623 / 154 = 4,04 cells.
You can almost fit 4 cells. 
So the optimal size is then: 623 / 4 = 155,75 points.

For the iPhone 7:  554 / 154 = 3,597 cells. 
Let's say we cannot reduce the size, then we would need 3 cells.
The new cell size = 554 / 3 = 185,666 points.

So in the case of a starting cell size of 154 you will need
two design sizes:

155,75 points and 185,66 points.

I think this can be done with size classes, but is there perhaps a
better approach to this?

[image]

Comment: Best size? The size adapted to the content of that cell. Showing the start of a cell at the bottom can also be used to show the user that there is more content and he can scroll. For the rest, it's up to you. You could use the tableView.frame.size.height, and calculate the optimum height (cellHeight > Y and numberOfCell being 4.5, or 3.5, etc.). But that's more about UX opinions and not that much of code.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised about your request. The partly hidden cell at the bottom indicates to the user that something is coming below and he can scroll to see more.

Nevertheless for your usecase you return in you ViewController (being the UITableViewDataSource) the height of your cells with `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and calculate it based on the point size of your screen.